# C++ Reference to non-static member function is required

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I am making a simple browser using QT5.

I have a `QMainWindow` with a `QWebEngineView` inside of it and I am trying to make it so that it auto accepts permission requests but I can't seem to get it to work... (Later I will make it prompt the user)

I looked online and found something but the solution didn't work for me as they set their application up differently than I did.

The `main.cpp` is simply the default with a declaration of `MainWindow` and showing it

`mainwindow.cpp`

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QUrl>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->view->page(), ui->view->page()->featurePermissionRequested, this, this->onFeaturePermissionRequested);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QString url = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QUrl curl;
    curl.setUrl(url);
    ui->view->setUrl(curl);
}

void MainWindow::on_back_pressed()
{
    ui->view->back();
}


void MainWindow::on_forward_pressed()
{
    ui->view->forward();
}


void MainWindow::on_reload_pressed()
{
    ui->view->reload();
}


void MainWindow::on_view_urlChanged(const QUrl &arg1)
{
    QString newurl = arg1.toString();
    QStringList urllist = newurl.split('?');
    ui->lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(urllist[0]);
}

void MainWindow::onFeaturePermissionRequested(const QUrl &securityOrigin, QWebEnginePage::Feature feature)
{
    ui->view->page()->setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QWebEnginePage::PermissionPolicy(1));
}
```

And the header file is as so:

`mainwindow.h`

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_returnPressed();

    void on_back_pressed();

    void on_forward_pressed();

    void on_reload_pressed();

    void on_view_urlChanged(const QUrl &arg1);

    void onFeaturePermissionRequested(const QUrl &securityOrigin, QWebEnginePage::Feature feature);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Whenever I attempt to build it I get these messages

```
/home/kiwifruit555/Documents/kUwU/Web/mainwindow.cpp:12: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void QWebEnginePage::featurePermissionRequested(const QUrl&, QWebEnginePage::Feature)’
../Web/mainwindow.cpp: In constructor ‘MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)’:
../Web/mainwindow.cpp:12:49: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void QWebEnginePage::featurePermissionRequested(const QUrl&, QWebEnginePage::Feature)’
   12 |     connect(ui->view->page(), ui->view->page()->featurePermissionRequested, this, this->onFeaturePermissionRequested);
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
/usr/include/qt/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEnginePage:1: In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEnginePage:1,
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEnginePage:1,
                 from ../Web/mainwindow.h:5,
                 from ../Web/mainwindow.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt/QtWebEngineWidgets/qwebenginepage.h:342:10: note: declared here
  342 |     void featurePermissionRequested(const QUrl &securityOrigin, QWebEnginePage::Feature feature);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried multiple things but I cannot seem to get it to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection syntax should be:

```
connect(ui->view->page(), &QWebEnginePage::featurePermissionRequested, this, &MainWindow::onFeaturePermissionRequested);
```

Fore more information read [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

It is also better to use the enum value explicitly instead of the numeric value:

```cpp
ui->view->page()->setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QWebEnginePage::PermissionGrantedByUser);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much! I’m not completely used to QT and CPP so I didn’t know that it had to be like that